# query for convert date time to persian calender

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

i have a database with a table name student
and 4 columns  Name,family,date Born
in  application i have 3 text box and data gridview 
date entered in database in date time "2013-05-01" but i wnt show in data gridview  in persian calender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use from `using System.Globalization` from your code behind as you see below:

```
public string Date(string yourDate)
{
    PersianCalendar pdate = new PersianCalendar();

    DateTime nT = new DateTime();

    nT = DateTime.Parse(yourDate);

    string s = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", pdate.GetYear(nT), pdate.GetMonth(nT), pdate.GetDayOfMonth(nT));

    return s;
}
```